# Give \printglossaries a section number and customize the name?

Tags: chapters, glossaries, indexing

When I print my glossary using \printglossaries it prints the glossary on a chapter level (at least it gives it the style of a chapter heading + it appears in the index on a chapter level). However, it doesn't get a chapter number. In the example below the result would be:
1. Content
A. First Appendix
Glossary

Does anybody know how I could give it the proper chapter number (= B. Glossary) in this case? Being able to customize the term "Glossary" on top of that would be even better.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Content}

\gls{sample}.

\Appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The numbered is dealt with via the `numberedsection` [package option](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sectioningheadingsandtocoptions). The title can be overridden using the `title` key in [`\printglossary`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec%3aprintglossary):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[numberedsection]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Content}

\gls{sample}.

\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}
\printglossary[title={Custom Title}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because [`autolabel`](https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#glo:optval.numberedsection.autolabel) has been officially provided in the [`numberedsection`](https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#glo:opt.numberedsection) for [`printglossary`](https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#glo:printglossaryhttps://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#glo:printglossary) command, the option setting on the command below could directly help achieve the expected result:

```
\printglossary[numberedsection=autolabel]
```